# ListView внутри ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, expandablelistview

Делаю ежедневник для Android-приложения. 
Есть `ListView`, в котором выводятся список текущих задач.
 Но у каждой задачи может быть Подзадача! Получается `ListView` внутри `ListView`. 
Как сделать такую вложенность?

P.S. `TreeView` и подобные уже перепробовал, не подходят под задачи. Есть еще варианты?

Comment: Вы бы хоть описали чем Вам TreeView то не подходит, а то по описанию проблемы Вам таки оно и надо.

Comment: ExpandableListView тебя не устраивает?

Comment: Такая задача, как правило, решается списком, в котором по клику на айтем осуществляется переход в другой список. Список в списке работать не будет из за конфликтов скролла.

Comment: Я так понял, что вам необходимо реализовать Master/Detail Flow. Если вы используете андройд студию, то там даже шаблон такой есть.

Answer (score 1):

Для того,что бы не было конфликтов скрола используйте  UI паттерн RecyclerView, в котором каждый елемент ListView